# How to dump AWT/Swing UI info on console on Linux GTK

Tags: java, swing, awt, dump, frames

I am working on a Java Swing application and I use Control + Shift + F1 key to get a dump of all UI details of the application while it is running for debugging purpose. This key prints all the child components to System.out every time the 'Ctrl+Shift+F1' keyboard combination is pressed. However, this is not working on Linux/Ubuntu/Java11 platform. It is using GTKLookAndFeel.

Any idea how to print this info?

Tried googling for found nothing.

Comment: Apparently [it was removed as of Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4379403).  I haven’t been able to determine if it can be explicitly enabled.

Comment: It appears the system property `awtdebug.on` can be set to `true` to enable Ctrl-Shift-F1, in theory, but I haven’t been able to get it to work.